# Does Heroku support client SSL certificates?

Tags: ssl, heroku

I can't for the life of me find how to configure client certificate validation with Heroku SSL endpoint. Is is supported at all? Is there an alternative add-on that does support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku's knowledgebase says they do not support certificate-based TLS authentication: https://help.heroku.com/3NTWIMNK/does-heroku-support-client-side-ssl-connections-a-k-a-two-way-authentication

So it would appear that server side verification of client certificates isn't supported by heroku right now if you rely upon their web server. I.e. having a server hosted on heroku check the client certificate provided by the connecting client. This requires a check at the web server level.

However I did come across this for nodejs:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/client-certificate-auth

which would lead me to believe that for nodejs is should be possible, since you have full access to the http(s) server. I haven't tried it though

Comment: I think it's because their SSL endpoint is backed by AWS ELB, which, in turn still doesn't support client-side SSL.

Comment: I think this solution cannot be used as SSL is offloaded by the router, application gets HTTP request.